# Intermittent Axios Get Request Failure

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a laravel and vue js application, I'm having intermittent issues with a get request with Vue JS & Axios, I can hit the route directly in my browser and it works fine the data is returned. I load my view which calls the data via Axios with Vue JS and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.. I find that if I open the debugger on the right of my chrome the call fires and it works fine. Close and it fails.

**Error being returned:**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

**My laravel route is as follows:**

```
Route::get('/orders/today','OrdersController@today');
```

**My vuejs file has the following:**

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#_token').getAttribute('value');

var vue = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {

        orders: [],
        estimates: []

    },

    mounted : function()
        {
           this.getOrders();   
        },

    methods: {

        getOrders: function() {

            axios.get('/orders/today').then(response => [this.orders = response.data.data, this.estimates = response.data.data2]);
            console.log(this.orders);
        }

    }

})
```

Comment: Not an answer but a tip here: axios by default pick `XSRF-TOKEN` in cookie and send it in every request as `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header which is recognized by laravel, so you need zero config for axios and laravel to work together on csrf prevention.

Comment: Better if you post the 500 response content here, you can see it in the Chrome dev tool or `console.log` it in axios' `catch` block, which is often chained after `then`.